# Extract substring between two specified substrings

Tags: r, regex, string-matching, substr

I have a list of substrings with the following pattern:

```
my.list <- list("file1\\subfile1-D.ext", "file12\\subfile9-D.ext", "file2\\subfile113-D.ext")
```

and so on. I'd like to extract the file numbers and the subfile-numbers into a numeric data frame containing the file/subfile numbers. So far, I've been using the following approach:

```
extract.file <- function(file.name){
  file.name <- sub("file", "", file.name)
  file.name <- sub("\\\\*subfile.*", "", file.name)
}

extract.subfile <- function(subfile.name){
  subfile.name <- sub("file.*subfile", "", subfile.name)
  subfile.name <- sub("-D.ext", "", subfile.name)
}

name.file <- lapply(my.list, extract.file)
name.file <- as.numeric(unlist(name.file))
name.subfile <- lapply(my.list, extract.subfile)
name.subfile <- as.numeric(unlist(name.subfile))

my.df <- data.frame(file=name.file, subfile=name.subfile)
```

I've also played around with first extracting the string locations with `substring.location` from `stringr` library (which yields another list with start and end values), and then looping over the two lists, but this gets too complicated again. Is there a better way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some alternatives:
[Edit: strsplit can take an array and return a list, and shaves time in about half compared to nesting an apply within the rbind call.]

```
my.df <- do.call( rbind, strsplit( unlist(my.list), split="(\\\\|-D.ext)" ) )
my.df <- data.frame( my.df )
names( my.df ) <- c("file", "subfile")
```

or

```
my.df <- do.call( rbind, strsplit( unlist(my.list), split="[^[:alnum:]]" ) )[, 1:2]
my.df <- data.frame( my.df )
names( my.df ) <- c("file", "subfile")
```

One thing about doing things this way is that you are left with pretty worthless and redundant data if all of the input follows the original `my.list` sample.

Perhaps a better solution might be;

```
# Not sure why strsplit() returns an empty string on the first non-digit match,
# but it does and we account for it by dropping the first returned column.
my.list <- unlist( my.list )
my.df <- do.call( rbind, strsplit( my.list, split="[^[:digit:]]+" ) )[,-1]
my.df <- data.frame( my.list, my.df )
names( my.df ) <- c( "orig", "file", "subfile" )
```

We've saved quite a bit of memory/storage without all of that duplication and we gain the ability to manipulate things without fussing with text/character ordering/representation.

---

Check `?strsplit`, `?regex`, and `?grep` for the matching stuff.

The data.frame setup is pretty straight forward...  strsplit takes a vector and returns a list, while do.call requires a list to bind together.

Comment: I find that `lapply` is safer than `sapply` when used with `do.call(rbind, ...)`.  After all, the `rbind` is doing the simplifying for you.

Comment: @Gsee, since `strsplit` is going to return a list and `lapply` will return a list then `unlist` with `recursive=FALSE` would be needed to pass the correct level of list to `rbind`, yes?

Comment: yes. You'd need `unlist` wrapped around the `strsplit`. I've got to start testing code before commenting. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up!  Made me go back and look again at strsplit output, which caused an edit in the answer. :)

Comment: @Thell That's perfect, exactly what I need to get as output, and in a really nice and clear way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex with backreferences that seems to do what you ask for:

```
sapply(my.list, function(x)gsub(".*\\\\(.*)-D\\.ext", "\\1", x))
[1] "subfile1"   "subfile9"   "subfile113"
```

---

The `"\\1"` is a backreference that returns the value of the string inside the parentheses.